Nashorn hitting limit with key value pairs?
I'm suddenly hitting a problem with Nashorn since making change, but Im not sure of the actual underlying cause of the problem but it seems to be related to how many key value pairs are added to engine
I use the Nashorn (Nashorn 15.3) Javascript engine in my Java application to allow customers to rename their music files based on metadata by defining a mask using known mask variables, there are about 200 mask variables.
For example user specifies a mask as artist - album
Then for each song we do the following:
ScriptEngine engine = new org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
for(SongFieldName next:SongFieldName.values())
{
  engine.put(next.getScriptVar(), song.getFieldValue(next.getSongFieldKey());
}
file.setFilename((String)engine.eval(mask));

So we get the script engine, and then for the song we put key value pairs containing mask variable (e.g artist) and actual value in song (e.g Stevie Wonder), then we evaluate the mask and use it to set the filename, this has worked fine for many years.
However, values can be multi value. For example the artist value may contain multiple people so I wanted there to be an easy way for use to just get the indexed value. So for each variable I created 10 versions each mapped to the next indexed value or blank if has no value as follows.
List<String> values = song.getFieldValues(next.getSongFieldKey());
for(int i=0; i < 10;i++)
{
    if(values.size()>i)
    {
        engine.put(next.getScriptVar() + "_index" + i,values.get(i));
    }
    else
    {
        engine.put(next.getScriptVar() + "_index" + i, "");
    }
}

This seemed fine but customer reported an issue, and I have replicated the issue that only occurs when this extra code is added.
JavascriptEngine seemingly randomly complains that discno field is not known variable even though it is always added.
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "discno" is not defined in <eval> at line number 81
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:463)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:447)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:395)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:151)
    at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:262)

So it seems that maybe I am hitting some limit and it is getting overwritten now that instead of adding 200 variables im adding aproximately 2000 variables to the engine?
For each song I tried clearing out the all value pairs first with engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).clear() and it still failed.
Or do I need to synchronize use of ScriptEngine since it is returned from a factory?
Update

I added synchronization code and it appeared to be working okay, but at about 10,000 songs it then started erroring with same error for every song.

The factory getScriptEngine() code is as follows


public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine() 
{
    try {
        return new NashornScriptEngine(this, DEFAULT_OPTIONS, getAppClassLoader(), (ClassFilter)null);
    } catch (RuntimeException var2) {
        RuntimeException e = var2;
        if (Context.DEBUG) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        throw e;
    }
}

so we are not reusing same script engine, but maybe script engine is sharing variable cache?

If I remove the new _index varaibles then it works without error but then I lose the functionality I was trying to add in the first place.

Update 2
I changed the code for the indexed variables to store an array for each fieldname, and that has resolved issue, although I dont know why.
    engine.put(next.getScriptVar(), cleanValue(next.getSongFieldKey(), song.getFieldValueSemiColonAndSpaceSeparatedOrEmptyString(next.getSongFieldKey())));
    addIndexedValues( engine, song,  next);

    private static void addIndexedValues( ScriptEngine engine, Song song, SongFieldName fieldName)
        {
            List<String> values = song.getFieldValues(fieldName.getSongFieldKey());
            String[] value = new String[INDEX_SIZE];
            for(int i=0; i < INDEX_SIZE;i++)
            {
                if(values.size()>i)
                {
                    value[i] = cleanValue(fieldName.getSongFieldKey(), values.get(i));
                }
                else
                {
                    value[i] = "";
                }
            }
            engine.put(fieldName.getScriptVar() + "_index", value);
        }


That last question just says "make a complete compilable example." Can you reproduce the issue in a simple environment.

Not easily, but I have worked out code that causes error so hoping someone with better knowledge of nashorn can see what Im doing wrong

It's just too abstract right now. Is discno (looks like disk number) is anywhere in your project? I doubt anybody can help you if you cannot create a reproducible example.

Note that Nashorn JavaScript engine is fairly outdated. It has been totally removed from Java 17, and was already deprecated in Java 11. Maybe there are better ways to achieve your goal than a complete scripting engine, but what you are trying to do at higher level is quite unclear.

@matt discno is just one of the variables, i dont think it matters that it happens to be discno. Ive already proved the issue is related to how many name value pairs are being added to the engine but i dont know the internal working of ther scriptengine, and writing a ssce will not chnage that.

@Quentic its removed from Java code, but now exista as standalone project, I dont want to make massive chnage just to fix one recent issue. You say higher level is unclear, maybe this help page from my webiste will make it clearer - https://community.jthink.net/t/tutorial-rename-files-renaming/11681

You haven't proved anything.

@matt you havewnt provided anything useful so far.

The way you say it, it seems like this could be a very simple example to reproduce. Create a script engine, and a bunch of variables until it stops working. You alluded to synchronization issues. You're talking about missing variables that we cannot see. I don't see how somebody can answer this without an SSCE, probably if you do make one you'll solve it yourself.

Why would you have "_index varaibles" instead of using a single array/object then reference it with the index?

@matt I wasnt aware you could store an array in the engine - I will try that.

I was just wondering if you needed to synchornize access to javascript engine, its not clear that you do since factory always seem to return new instance, and these instances are not shared by multiple processes.

Adding elements to the array could be a good question. I know how to do it with javascript, but you're directly adding a reference to the script engine which doesn't seem as straight forward. As far as synchronization, the script engine api offers you an interface to mutable state without any synchronization guarantees. So yes. If you are using multiple threads to access a single engine, you should synchronize the calls somehow.

@matt So I changed code to store an array rather than 10 values per variable, and that has fixed the issue. Note im not actually using any of these indexed varaibles in my script im just guessing that it is now avoiding some limit I was hitting before. I was not using multiple threads with same engine, each file procesed uses a new engine so I dont think symchrnoization was an issue.

If you are using the script engine concurrently in different threads, you'll want each thread to have its own Bindings instance (and use the version of eval that accepts a Bindings) rather than have them all race with the default bindings concurrently.

You can create a new ScriptEngine instance for each evaluation.or use different data structures then it is a good way to handle the problem.

This is probably a good comment, and it is why the OP needs to make a reproducible example. It is not a good answer.
